# Get raw text from textarea with javascript and send it to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a textarea where I put some C++ code, then I get that code with javascript and send it to a PHP script via AJAX to be processed. The problem is that the code gets corrupted in the way.

Here is my code:

```
function showResult()
{
  var code  = document.getElementById('code').value;
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

  if (code != '') {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ideone.php?code=' + code + '&input=' + input, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo 'Code: '.$_GET['code']; // Empty string
?>
```

Comment: what does `alert(document.getElementById('code').value);` give you?

Comment: It might be worth trying [`var code = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('code').value);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) just to be sure that the url is appropriately encoded for inserting to the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote your query string:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ideone.php?code=' + encodeURIComponent(code) + '&input=' + encodeURIComponent(input), true);
```

Comment: And really, you should be using POST.  This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: I know that POST is more secure but I am only testing. Thanks for advice.

Comment: It's not a matter of security, but a matter of limitations. GET requests have shorter maximum length, while POST requests could have much longer content.